# What is this app called?

Tags: applications, dock, network

the app in the dock (right of Safari) apparently shows the network speeds in the dock.

[image: The app in question is the second one from the left]

Does anyone know what the app is called?
There are more images of the app in the blog post at [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/seven-tricks-to-tweak-the-dock-mac/)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The app is [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/).

> [Transmission is a cross-platform BitTorrent client that is Open Source, Easy, Lean, Native and Powerful.](http://www.transmissionbt.com/about/)

Comment: And the value displayed on the badge is either the total download rate or total upload rate for all the torrents currently being managed by the app.

Comment: Also, if your question was partially because you are looking for an application to display network statistics, have a look at [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/)

Answer (score 0):

There is an app for upload and download speed though, along with disk access and cpu usage, all shown in the menu bar at the top: http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/.

Comment: Thanks - it is just not as pretty as Transmission. :)